# Calling an object method recursively

Tags: javascript

I'd like to call recursively an object method like so:

```
...
let t = 0;

const Obj = {
  val1: 9,
  fun: () => {
    console.log("t: ", t);
    if(t++<3)
      fun()
  }
};

...
Obj.fun();
```

but getting an error: `fun is not defined`

Why isn't it possible to call a object method this way?

Comment: Please share more details. How did you run `fun` in the first place?

Comment: put Obj.fun inside and call it. see lexical scope, this.

Comment: you want `Obj.fun()`. (`this.fun()` could in theory work, depending on how you call it - except it definitely won't when `fun` is defined as an arrow function as you are doing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to refer to `Obj.fun()`

```js
let t = 0;

const Obj = {
  val1: 9,
  fun: () => {
    console.log("t: ", t);
    if(t++<3)
      Obj.fun()
  }
};

Obj.fun()
```

Some other options, you can refer to `this` as long as you make it a traditional function not an arrow

```js
let t = 0;

const Obj = {
  val1: 9,
  fun: function(){
    console.log("t: ", t);
    if(t++<3)
      this.fun()
  }
};

Obj.fun()
```

But this *won't* work if the context of `this` changes - for example by using in an event handler where `this` will instead refer to the element being clicked.

```js
let t = 0;

const Obj = {
  val1: 9,
  fun: function(){
    console.log("t: ", t);
    if(t++<3)
      this.fun()
  }
};

// THIS WILL FAIL AFER FIRST CALL
document.getElementById("clickme").addEventListener("click",Obj.fun);
```

```html
<button id="clickme">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Ok, but why do i have to use `Obj` prefix? The `fun` method is defined INSIDE the `Obj` object so it should (intuitively) be accessed just by it's name...

Comment: But it's not "defined inside Obj" is it? It's a _property_ of `Obj`

Comment: "It's a property of Obj" - doesn't it already mean that it's defined here!?

Comment: @Daros911 no. Just `fun()` implies global or local scope, but that function is not in global or local scope

Comment: So what scope does it have?

Comment: ? Could You be so nice and answer my last question?

Comment: @Daros911 `fun()` is in the scope of the object `Obj` which is why you need to prefix the call `Obj`. I'm not saying the rules of scoping in javascript are straightforward (anything but!) so you might like to read up on it - there is lots to learn and it is often counter intuative.